# Error "Maximum call stack size exceeded" cuando uso un componente con fetch

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Tengo este componente que trae datos de una API:

```
class GetDPIData extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      data: null
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/api/dpi/')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ data }))
  }
}
```

Y cuando lo agrego a otro componente (tipo `<GetDPIData />`), falla con el siguiente mensaje de error:

> ```
> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>     at Object.asyncReconciledRender [as componentWillRender] 
>     (react-hot-loader.development.js:1507)
> ```

Ahora bien, los reportes de error encontrados en la red, se refieren a una mala configuración de `react-hot-loader` o `webpack-dev-server`, pero en mi caso, este error aparece **unicamente al agregrar el componente `GetDPIData`**, mientras no se cargue este componente, todo funciona como se espera.

He intentado no usar funciones de flecha, pasando `componentDidMount()` a esto:

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch('/api/dpi/')
    .then(function(res) {
      return res.json()
    }
    .then(function(data) {
      this.setState({ data })
    }
}
```

Igual sin éxito.

El error completo es:

> ```
> react-hot-loader.development.js:1491 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>     at renderReconciler (react-hot-loader.development.js:1491)
>     at Object.asyncReconciledRender [as componentWillRender] (react-hot-loader.development.js:1508)
>     at ProxyComponent.hotComponentRender (react-hot-loader.development.js:608)
>     at ProxyComponent.proxiedRender (react-hot-loader.development.js:635)
>     at ProxyComponent.hotComponentRender (react-hot-loader.development.js:620)
>     at ProxyComponent.proxiedRender (react-hot-loader.development.js:635)
>     at ProxyComponent.hotComponentRender (react-hot-loader.development.js:620)
>     at ProxyComponent.proxiedRender (react-hot-loader.development.js:635)
>     at ProxyComponent.hotComponentRender (react-hot-loader.development.js:620)
>     at ProxyComponent.proxiedRender (react-hot-loader.development.js:635)
> renderReconciler @ react-hot-loader.development.js:1491
> asyncReconciledRender @ react-hot-loader.development.js:1508
> hotComponentRender @ react-hot-loader.development.js:608
> proxiedRender @ react-hot-loader.development.js:635
> hotComponentRender @ react-hot-loader.development.js:620
> proxiedRender @ react-hot-loader.development.js:635
>
> ...
> Muchas líneas iguales que se repiten...
> ...
>
> hotComponentRender @ react-hot-loader.development.js:620
> proxiedRender @ react-hot-loader.development.js:635
> react-dom.development.js:14389 The above error occurred in the <GetDPIData> component:
>     in GetDPIData (created by DPI)
>     in div (created by DPI)
>     in DPI (created by Route)
>     in Route (created by App)
>     in div (created by App)
>     in App
>     in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
>     in BrowserRouter
> ```

### Actualización

El error persiste cuando uso la librería Axios:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('/api/dpi/')
      .then(res => {
        data = res.data
        this.setState({ data })
      })
    }
  }
```

### Actualización II

Al pasar el código de `componentDidMount()` al componente padre, todo funciona correctamente como se espera. Por lo que parece ser un error al combinar `react-hot-loader`, '`fetch()` y un componente...

Comment: ¿Qué hace this.setState? ¿Has probado a poner this.setState({ res.data })) ? ¿La variable data que estableces ahí es local a esa función?

Comment: `data` es local para _resolver_ la promesa. Tal como está en la pregunta, `this.state.data` devuelve `undefined`.

Comment: Intenta comentar la línea this.setState y poner un console.log sobre res, por probar

Comment: El error persiste, no importa que use el `state` o no... por otro lado, si paso el código de `componentDidMount()` al componente padre, **todo funciona correctamente**.